Different Groebner bases in 12.1 and 13.3 with the same code
With exactly the same code I get different Groebner bases with different versions of Mathematica. Even worse, with exactly the same code I get a Groebner basis with a version of the program but I cannot get a basis with a different version. Moreover, I don't find changes in this Mathematica function since 2007.
Someone can explain how this is possible?
Thanks in advance!
Next code (copying and pasting) gives a good basis (16 elements) in few seconds (version 13.3), but does not give a basis in version 12.1.

(**********)
varsI = {\[Kappa], \[Lambda], \[Gamma]1, \[Gamma]2, \[Gamma]3, X[1], 
   X[2], X[3], X[4]};

idealI = {2 \[Kappa] + 3 \[Gamma]1 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2), 
   6 + 24 \[Gamma]1^2 + 9 \[Gamma]1 \[Kappa] - 
    8 \[Gamma]2 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda], 
   17 \[Gamma]1 + 24 \[Gamma]1^2 \[Kappa] - 
    4 (\[Gamma]2^2 + \[Gamma]3^2) \[Lambda], 
   1/24 \[Lambda] (-8 (4 \[Gamma]1 - \[Kappa]) (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) X[
        2] + 8 \[Gamma]2^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2)^2 \[Lambda] X[2] + 
      8 \[Gamma]3^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2)^2 \[Lambda] X[
        2] + \[Gamma]3 (\[Lambda] (-9 - 3 \[Kappa]^2 + 
            16 \[Gamma]2 \[Kappa]^5 X[2] + 
            8 \[Kappa] (2 \[Gamma]2 X[2] - 3 X[3]) - 
            8 \[Kappa]^3 (4 \[Gamma]2 X[2] - 3 X[3])) - 
         24 \[Gamma]1 \[Kappa] (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) X[4]) + 
      3 \[Gamma]2 (-6 \[Lambda] X[
           3] + \[Kappa] (7 \[Lambda] - 4 X[4]) + 
         6 \[Gamma]1 X[4] + \[Kappa]^3 (-3 \[Lambda] + 4 X[4]) + 
         4 \[Kappa]^2 (\[Lambda] X[3] - \[Gamma]1 X[4]) + 
         2 \[Kappa]^4 (\[Lambda] X[3] - \[Gamma]1 X[4]))), -(1/
       24) \[Lambda] (-8 (4 \[Gamma]1 - \[Kappa]) (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) X[
        1] + 8 \[Gamma]2^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2)^2 \[Lambda] X[1] + 
      8 \[Gamma]3^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2)^2 \[Lambda] X[
        1] + \[Gamma]2 (\[Lambda] (-9 - 3 \[Kappa]^2 + 
            16 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa]^5 X[1] + 
            8 \[Kappa] (2 \[Gamma]3 X[1] + 3 X[3]) - 
            8 \[Kappa]^3 (4 \[Gamma]3 X[1] + 3 X[3])) + 
         24 \[Gamma]1 \[Kappa] (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) X[4]) - 
      3 \[Gamma]3 (-6 \[Lambda] X[3] + 
         6 \[Gamma]1 X[
           4] + \[Kappa]^3 (3 \[Lambda] + 
            4 X[4]) - \[Kappa] (7 \[Lambda] + 4 X[4]) + 
         4 \[Kappa]^2 (\[Lambda] X[3] - \[Gamma]1 X[4]) + 
         2 \[Kappa]^4 (\[Lambda] X[3] - \[Gamma]1 X[4]))), -(1/
       4) \[Lambda]^2 (16 \[Gamma]1 \[Kappa] + (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) (2 \
\[Gamma]2^2 \[Kappa] \[Lambda] + \[Gamma]2 (\[Gamma]3 (3 + \
\[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] + (3 + \[Kappa]^2) X[1] + 
            4 \[Kappa] X[
              2]) + \[Gamma]3 (2 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa] \[Lambda] + 
            4 \[Kappa] X[1] + 3 X[2] + \[Kappa]^2 X[2]))), -(1/
       4) \[Lambda] (2 \[Gamma]1 \[Kappa]^2 (\[Gamma]2 \[Gamma]3 \
\[Lambda] - \[Gamma]2 X[1] - \[Gamma]3 X[
           2]) + \[Gamma]1 \[Kappa]^4 (\[Gamma]2 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] \
- \[Gamma]2 X[1] - \[Gamma]3 X[2]) + 
      3 \[Gamma]1 (\[Gamma]2 (-\[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] + 
            X[1]) + \[Gamma]3 X[2]) + 
      2 \[Kappa] (1 + 
         8 \[Gamma]1^2 + \[Gamma]2 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] - \[Gamma]2 X[
           1] - \[Gamma]3 X[
           2] - \[Gamma]1 (\[Gamma]2^2 \[Lambda] + \[Gamma]3^2 \
\[Lambda] - 2 \[Gamma]3 X[1] - 2 \[Gamma]2 X[2])) + 
      2 \[Kappa]^3 (-\[Gamma]2 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] + \[Gamma]2 X[
           1] + \[Gamma]3 X[
           2] + \[Gamma]1 (\[Gamma]2^2 \[Lambda] + \[Gamma]3^2 \
\[Lambda] - 2 \[Gamma]3 X[1] - 2 \[Gamma]2 X[2]))), -(1/
       24) \[Lambda] (3 \[Gamma]2 \[Kappa]^4 \[Lambda] (5 \[Gamma]2 \
\[Lambda] - 2 X[2]) + 
      16 \[Gamma]1 ((3 + 6 \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] + X[4]) + 
      4 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa]^3 \[Lambda] (9 \[Gamma]2 \[Lambda] - 
         6 X[2] - 
         2 \[Gamma]2 X[4]) + \[Lambda] (18 \[Gamma]2 X[
           2] + \[Gamma]3^2 (-15 \[Lambda] + 
            4 X[4]) + \[Gamma]2^2 (-6 \[Lambda] + 
            4 X[4])) - \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda] (12 \[Gamma]2 X[2] + 
         48 X[3] + \[Gamma]3^2 (-15 \[Lambda] + 
            4 X[4]) + \[Gamma]2^2 (9 \[Lambda] + 4 X[4])) - 
      4 \[Kappa] (9 \[Gamma]2 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda]^2 + 
         X[4] - \[Lambda] (3 + 6 \[Gamma]3 X[2] + 
            2 \[Gamma]2 \[Gamma]3 X[4]))), -(1/
       24) \[Lambda] (\[Gamma]2^2 \[Kappa] (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \
\[Lambda] (9 \[Lambda] - 4 X[4]) + 
      16 \[Gamma]1 \[Kappa] (3 \[Lambda] + 
         X[4]) + \[Gamma]2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] (3 \[Gamma]3 \
(3 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] + 6 (3 + \[Kappa]^2) X[1] - 
         8 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa]^2 X[
           4]) + \[Kappa] (24 \[Gamma]3 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] X[
           1] + \[Gamma]3^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] (3 \[Lambda] \
- 4 X[4]) - 4 (12 \[Lambda] X[3] + \[Kappa] X[4]))), -(1/
       4) \[Lambda]^2 (8 \[Kappa] X[
        2] + \[Gamma]2 \[Kappa] (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) (\[Lambda] - 
         X[4]) + 3 \[Gamma]3 X[
        4] + \[Kappa]^2 (8 X[1] - 3 \[Gamma]3 X[4])), 
   1/24 \[Lambda] (6 \[Gamma]2^3 \[Kappa] (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \
\[Lambda]^2 + 
      2 \[Gamma]2^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] (3 \[Gamma]3 (\
\[Lambda] + 2 \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda]) - 
         2 (X[1] + \[Kappa] X[2])) + \[Gamma]2 \[Lambda] (-9 + 
         6 \[Gamma]1 \[Kappa] (7 + \[Kappa]^2) - 
         8 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa]^4 X[
           2] + \[Kappa]^2 (3 + 8 \[Gamma]3 X[2]) + 
         2 \[Kappa]^3 (9 \[Gamma]3^2 \[Lambda] - 4 \[Gamma]3 X[1] - 
            3 X[3]) + \[Kappa] (-18 \[Gamma]3^2 \[Lambda] + 
            8 \[Gamma]3 X[1] + 6 X[3])) + 
      2 (3 \[Gamma]3^3 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda]^2 + 
         6 \[Gamma]1 \[Gamma]3 (\[Lambda] + 3 \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda]) + 
         8 \[Gamma]1 (X[1] + \[Kappa] X[2]) - 
         2 \[Kappa] (X[1] + \[Kappa] X[2]) - 
         2 \[Gamma]3^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] (X[
             1] + \[Kappa] X[2]) + 
         9 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] (\[Kappa] + X[3] - \[Kappa]^2 X[3]))), 
   1/24 (-48 \[Gamma]1^2 (\[Lambda] + 
         2 \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda] - \[Kappa]^2 X[
           4]) + \[Gamma]1 (-12 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa]^3 \[Lambda] (3 \
\[Gamma]2 \[Lambda] + 2 X[2]) - 
         3 \[Gamma]2 \[Kappa]^4 \[Lambda] (5 \[Gamma]2 \[Lambda] + 
            2 X[2]) + 
         3 \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda] (3 \[Gamma]2^2 \[Lambda] - 
            5 \[Gamma]3^2 \[Lambda] - 
            4 \[Gamma]2 X[2]) + \[Lambda] (6 \[Gamma]2^2 \[Lambda] + 
            15 \[Gamma]3^2 \[Lambda] + 18 \[Gamma]2 X[2] - 16 X[3]) + 
         12 \[Kappa] (3 \[Gamma]2 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda]^2 + \[Lambda] \
(-3 + 2 \[Gamma]3 X[2]) + 2 X[4])) + 
      2 \[Lambda] (2 \[Kappa] X[
           3] + \[Gamma]3^2 \[Lambda] (-3 \[Kappa] - 2 X[3] + 
            2 \[Kappa]^2 X[3]) + 
         2 \[Gamma]2 \[Kappa] (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) (3 X[2] + 
            2 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] X[3]) + \[Gamma]2^2 (-2 \[Lambda] X[
              3] + 2 \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda] X[3] + 
            12 \[Kappa] (\[Lambda] - 
               X[4]) + \[Kappa]^3 (-9 \[Lambda] + 12 X[4])))), 
   1/24 (\[Gamma]2 \[Kappa]^4 \[Lambda] (-3 \[Gamma]1 \[Gamma]3 \
\[Lambda] + 6 \[Gamma]1 X[1] + 
         8 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] X[
           3]) + \[Kappa]^3 \[Lambda] (-3 \[Gamma]1 (3 \[Gamma]2^2 \
\[Lambda] + \[Gamma]3 (\[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] - 8 X[1])) + 
         6 \[Gamma]2 (\[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] - 2 X[1]) + 
         4 \[Gamma]2^2 \[Lambda] X[3] + 
         4 \[Gamma]3^2 \[Lambda] X[
           3]) + \[Kappa] (-2 \[Lambda] (3 + 24 \[Gamma]1^2 - 
            6 \[Gamma]2 X[1] + 12 \[Gamma]1 \[Gamma]3 X[1] + 
            8 \[Gamma]1 X[
              3]) + \[Lambda]^2 (9 \[Gamma]1 \[Gamma]2^2 - 
            6 \[Gamma]2 \[Gamma]3 + 3 \[Gamma]1 \[Gamma]3^2 - 
            4 \[Gamma]2^2 X[3] - 4 \[Gamma]3^2 X[3]) + 
         48 \[Gamma]1^2 X[4]) + 
      3 (3 \[Gamma]1 \[Gamma]2 \[Lambda] (\[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] - 
            2 X[1]) + 8 \[Gamma]1 X[4] - 
         4 (\[Gamma]2^2 + \[Gamma]3^2) \[Lambda] X[4]) + 
      2 \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda] (2 X[
           3] + \[Gamma]2 (-3 \[Gamma]1 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] + 
            6 \[Gamma]1 X[1] - 4 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] X[3]) - 
         3 \[Gamma]3^2 (\[Lambda] - 2 X[4]) + 
         3 \[Gamma]2^2 (\[Lambda] + 2 X[4]))), -(1/
       12) \[Lambda] (-3 \[Gamma]2 \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda] - 
      3 \[Gamma]2^3 \[Kappa] \[Lambda]^2 + 
      3 \[Gamma]2^3 \[Kappa]^3 \[Lambda]^2 + 
      3 \[Gamma]3^3 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda]^2 + 2 \[Kappa] X[1] - 
      2 \[Gamma]2^2 \[Lambda] X[1] + 
      2 \[Gamma]2^2 \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda] X[1] + 2 \[Kappa]^2 X[2] - 
      2 \[Gamma]2^2 \[Kappa] \[Lambda] X[2] + 
      2 \[Gamma]2^2 \[Kappa]^3 \[Lambda] X[
        2] + \[Gamma]3^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] (9 \[Gamma]2 \
\[Kappa] \[Lambda] + 2 (X[1] + \[Kappa] X[2])) + 
      6 \[Gamma]2 \[Kappa]^2 X[
        4] + \[Gamma]3 (-3 \[Gamma]2^2 \[Lambda]^2 + 
         4 \[Gamma]2 \[Kappa]^3 \[Lambda] X[
           1] + \[Kappa] \[Lambda] (3 - 4 \[Gamma]2 X[1]) + 
         2 \[Gamma]2 \[Kappa]^4 \[Lambda] (3 \[Gamma]2 \[Lambda] + 
            2 X[2]) - \[Gamma]2 \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda] (3 \[Gamma]2 \
\[Lambda] + 4 X[2]) - 
         6 \[Kappa] X[
           4]) + \[Gamma]1 (6 \[Gamma]3 (1 + 
            3 \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] - 8 (X[1] + \[Kappa] X[2]) - 
         9 \[Gamma]3 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) X[4] + 
         3 \[Gamma]2 \[Kappa] ((7 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] - (-1 + \
\[Kappa]^2) X[4]))), 
   1/8 (2 \[Gamma]1^2 \[Kappa] (\[Gamma]2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] \
- 8 (\[Kappa] X[1] + X[2])) + \[Gamma]1 (-8 (\[Kappa] X[1] + X[2]) + 
         2 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] (8 \[Kappa] + 3 X[3] - 
            3 \[Kappa]^2 X[
              3]) + \[Gamma]2 \[Lambda] (-5 + \[Kappa]^2 + 
            2 \[Kappa] X[3] - 2 \[Kappa]^3 X[3])) + 
      2 \[Lambda] (\[Gamma]2^3 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] + 
         2 \[Gamma]2^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) (\[Gamma]3 \[Kappa] \
\[Lambda] - 2 \[Kappa] X[1] - X[2]) - 
         2 \[Gamma]3 (\[Gamma]3 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) X[2] + \[Kappa] X[
              3]) + \[Gamma]2 (-3 \[Kappa] - \[Gamma]3^2 \[Lambda] + \
\[Kappa]^2 (\[Gamma]3^2 \[Lambda] + 2 X[3])))), 
   1/24 \[Lambda] (-9 \[Gamma]3^2 \[Kappa] \[Lambda]^2 + 
      9 \[Gamma]3^2 \[Kappa]^3 \[Lambda]^2 - 
      18 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] X[2] + 
      12 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda] X[2] + 
      6 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa]^4 \[Lambda] X[2] + 
      48 \[Kappa] \[Lambda] X[3] + 
      16 \[Gamma]1 \[Kappa] (3 \[Lambda] - X[4]) + 
      4 \[Kappa]^2 X[4] - 4 \[Gamma]3^2 \[Kappa] \[Lambda] X[4] + 
      4 \[Gamma]3^2 \[Kappa]^3 \[Lambda] X[
        4] + \[Gamma]2^2 \[Kappa] (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] (3 \
\[Lambda] + 
         4 X[4]) + \[Gamma]2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] (3 \[Gamma]3 \
(3 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] + 24 \[Kappa] X[2] + 
         8 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa]^2 X[4])), 
   1/24 \[Lambda] (3 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa]^4 \[Lambda] (5 \[Gamma]3 \
\[Lambda] - 2 X[1]) + 
      16 \[Gamma]1 ((3 + 6 \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] - X[4]) + 
      4 \[Gamma]2 \[Kappa]^3 \[Lambda] (9 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] - 
         6 X[1] + 
         2 \[Gamma]3 X[4]) + \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda] (-12 \[Gamma]3 X[
           1] + 48 X[
           3] + \[Gamma]3^2 (-9 \[Lambda] + 
            4 X[4]) + \[Gamma]2^2 (15 \[Lambda] + 
            4 X[4])) - \[Lambda] (\[Gamma]2^2 (15 \[Lambda] + 
            4 X[4]) + 
         2 \[Gamma]3 (3 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] - 9 X[1] + 
            2 \[Gamma]3 X[4])) - 
      4 \[Kappa] (9 \[Gamma]2 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda]^2 - 
         X[4] + \[Lambda] (-3 - 6 \[Gamma]2 X[1] + 
            2 \[Gamma]2 \[Gamma]3 X[4]))), -(1/
       4) \[Lambda]^2 (8 \[Kappa] X[1] - 
      3 \[Gamma]2 X[
        4] + \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa] (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) (\[Lambda] + 
         X[4]) + \[Kappa]^2 (8 X[2] + 3 \[Gamma]2 X[4])), 
   1/24 \[Lambda] (6 \[Gamma]2^3 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda]^2 + 
      6 \[Gamma]3^3 \[Kappa] (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda]^2 - 
      4 \[Kappa] (\[Kappa] X[1] + X[2]) - 
      4 \[Gamma]2^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] (\[Kappa] X[1] + 
         X[2]) + 2 \[Gamma]3^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] (3 \
\[Gamma]2 (\[Lambda] + 2 \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda]) - 
         2 (\[Kappa] X[1] + X[2])) + 
      2 \[Gamma]1 (3 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa] (7 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] + 
         6 \[Gamma]2 (\[Lambda] + 3 \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda]) + 
         8 (\[Kappa] X[1] + X[2])) + 
      18 \[Gamma]2 \[Lambda] (\[Kappa] - 
         X[3] + \[Kappa]^2 X[3]) + \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] (-9 - 
         8 \[Gamma]2 \[Kappa]^4 X[
           1] + \[Kappa]^2 (3 + 8 \[Gamma]2 X[1]) - 
         2 \[Kappa] (9 \[Gamma]2^2 \[Lambda] - 4 \[Gamma]2 X[2] + 
            3 X[3]) + 
         2 \[Kappa]^3 (9 \[Gamma]2^2 \[Lambda] - 4 \[Gamma]2 X[2] + 
            3 X[3]))), 
   1/24 (\[Gamma]3 \[Kappa]^4 \[Lambda] (3 \[Gamma]1 \[Gamma]2 \
\[Lambda] - 6 \[Gamma]1 X[2] + 
         8 \[Gamma]2 \[Lambda] X[
           3]) + \[Kappa]^3 \[Lambda] (-6 \[Gamma]2 \[Gamma]3 \
\[Lambda] + 
         3 \[Gamma]1 (\[Gamma]2^2 \[Lambda] + 
            3 \[Gamma]3^2 \[Lambda] - 8 \[Gamma]2 X[2]) + 
         4 \[Gamma]2^2 \[Lambda] X[3] + 
         4 \[Gamma]3 (3 X[2] + \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] X[
              3])) + \[Kappa] (2 \[Lambda] (3 + 24 \[Gamma]1^2 + 
            12 \[Gamma]1 \[Gamma]2 X[2] - 6 \[Gamma]3 X[2] - 
            8 \[Gamma]1 X[3]) - \[Lambda]^2 (-6 \[Gamma]2 \[Gamma]3 + 
            3 \[Gamma]1 (\[Gamma]2^2 + 3 \[Gamma]3^2) + 
            4 \[Gamma]2^2 X[3] + 4 \[Gamma]3^2 X[3]) + 
         48 \[Gamma]1^2 X[4]) - 
      3 (\[Gamma]1 (3 \[Gamma]2 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda]^2 - 
            6 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] X[2] - 8 X[4]) + 
         4 (\[Gamma]2^2 + \[Gamma]3^2) \[Lambda] X[4]) + 
      2 \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda] (-6 \[Gamma]1 \[Gamma]3 X[
           2] + \[Gamma]2 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] (3 \[Gamma]1 - 
            4 X[3]) + 2 X[3] - 3 \[Gamma]3^2 (\[Lambda] - 2 X[4]) + 
         3 \[Gamma]2^2 (\[Lambda] + 2 X[4]))), 
   1/24 (\[Gamma]1 (12 \[Gamma]2 \[Kappa]^3 \[Lambda] (3 \[Gamma]3 \
\[Lambda] + 2 X[1]) + 
         3 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa]^4 \[Lambda] (5 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] + 
            2 X[1]) + 
         3 \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda] (5 \[Gamma]2^2 \[Lambda] + \[Gamma]3 \
(-3 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] + 
               4 X[1])) - \[Lambda] (15 \[Gamma]2^2 \[Lambda] + 
            6 \[Gamma]3^2 \[Lambda] + 18 \[Gamma]3 X[1] + 16 X[3]) - 
         12 \[Kappa] (3 \[Gamma]2 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda]^2 + \[Lambda] \
(-3 + 2 \[Gamma]2 X[1]) - 2 X[4])) + 
      48 \[Gamma]1^2 (\[Lambda] + 
         2 \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda] + \[Kappa]^2 X[4]) + 
      2 \[Lambda] (-6 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa] (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) X[1] + 
         2 \[Kappa] X[3] + 
         4 \[Gamma]2 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa] (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] X[
           3] + \[Gamma]2^2 \[Lambda] (3 \[Kappa] - 2 X[3] + 
            2 \[Kappa]^2 X[3]) + \[Gamma]3^2 (-2 \[Lambda] X[3] + 
            2 \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda] X[3] - 
            12 \[Kappa] (\[Lambda] + X[4]) + 
            3 \[Kappa]^3 (3 \[Lambda] + 4 X[4])))), -(1/
       12) \[Lambda] (-3 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda] - 
      3 \[Gamma]3^3 \[Kappa] \[Lambda]^2 + 
      3 \[Gamma]3^3 \[Kappa]^3 \[Lambda]^2 + 
      3 \[Gamma]2^3 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda]^2 + 
      2 \[Kappa]^2 X[1] - 2 \[Gamma]3^2 \[Kappa] \[Lambda] X[1] + 
      2 \[Gamma]3^2 \[Kappa]^3 \[Lambda] X[1] + 2 \[Kappa] X[2] - 
      2 \[Gamma]3^2 \[Lambda] X[2] + 
      2 \[Gamma]3^2 \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda] X[
        2] + \[Gamma]2^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] (9 \[Gamma]3 \
\[Kappa] \[Lambda] + 2 (\[Kappa] X[1] + X[2])) - 
      6 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa]^2 X[
        4] + \[Gamma]2 (-3 \[Gamma]3^2 \[Lambda]^2 + 
         2 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa]^4 \[Lambda] (3 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] + 
            2 X[1]) - \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda] (3 \[Gamma]3 \
\[Lambda] + 4 X[1]) + 
         4 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa]^3 \[Lambda] X[
           2] + \[Kappa] \[Lambda] (3 - 4 \[Gamma]3 X[2]) + 
         6 \[Kappa] X[4]) + \[Gamma]1 (-8 (\[Kappa] X[1] + X[2]) + 
         3 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa] ((7 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] + (-1 + \
\[Kappa]^2) X[4]) + 
         3 \[Gamma]2 ((2 + 6 \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] + 
            3 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) X[4]))), 
   1/8 (2 \[Gamma]1^2 \[Kappa] (\[Gamma]3 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] \
- 8 (X[1] + \[Kappa] X[2])) + 
      2 \[Lambda] (\[Gamma]3^3 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] + 
         2 \[Gamma]3^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) (\[Gamma]2 \[Kappa] \
\[Lambda] - X[1] - 
            2 \[Kappa] X[
              
              2]) + \[Gamma]3 (-3 \[Kappa] - \[Gamma]2^2 \[Lambda] + \
\[Kappa]^2 (\[Gamma]2^2 \[Lambda] - 2 X[3])) + 
         2 \[Gamma]2 (-\[Gamma]2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) X[1] + \[Kappa] X[
              3])) + \[Gamma]1 (-8 (X[1] + \[Kappa] X[2]) + 
         2 \[Gamma]2 \[Lambda] (8 \[Kappa] - 3 X[3] + 
            3 \[Kappa]^2 X[
              3]) + \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] (-5 + \[Kappa]^2 - 
            2 \[Kappa] X[3] + 2 \[Kappa]^3 X[3]))), -(1/
       8) \[Lambda] (4 \[Gamma]2^3 \[Kappa] (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \
\[Lambda]^2 + 
      4 \[Gamma]2^2 \[Gamma]3 (-1 - \[Kappa]^2 + 
         2 \[Kappa]^4) \[Lambda]^2 + 
      2 \[Gamma]3 (4 \[Gamma]1 (1 + 
            3 \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] + \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda] (2 \
\[Gamma]3^2 \[Lambda] - 
            3 X[3]) + \[Lambda] (-2 \[Gamma]3^2 \[Lambda] + 
            3 X[3]) + \[Kappa] (4 \[Lambda] - 2 X[4]) - 
         3 \[Gamma]1 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) X[
           4]) + \[Gamma]2 (12 \[Gamma]3^2 \[Kappa] (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \
\[Lambda]^2 + \[Lambda] (-3 - \[Kappa]^2 + 
            4 \[Gamma]1 \[Kappa] (7 + \[Kappa]^2) + 2 \[Kappa] X[3] - 
            2 \[Kappa]^3 X[3]) + 
         2 \[Kappa] (\[Gamma]1 + 2 \[Kappa] - \[Gamma]1 \[Kappa]^2) X[
           4])), -(1/
       8) \[Lambda] (4 \[Gamma]3^3 \[Kappa] (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \
\[Lambda]^2 + 
      4 \[Gamma]2 \[Gamma]3^2 (-1 - \[Kappa]^2 + 
         2 \[Kappa]^4) \[Lambda]^2 + \[Gamma]3 (12 \[Gamma]2^2 \
\[Kappa] (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda]^2 + \[Lambda] (-3 - \[Kappa]^2 - 
            2 \[Kappa] X[3] + 2 \[Kappa]^3 X[3]) - 
         4 \[Kappa]^2 X[4]) + 
      2 \[Gamma]1 (2 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa] (7 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] + 
         4 \[Gamma]2 (1 + 3 \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] + 
         3 \[Gamma]2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) X[
           4] + \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa] (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) X[4]) + 
      2 \[Gamma]2 (-\[Lambda] (2 \[Gamma]2^2 \[Lambda] + 
            3 X[3]) + \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda] (2 \[Gamma]2^2 \[Lambda] + 
            3 X[3]) + 2 \[Kappa] (2 \[Lambda] + X[4]))), 
   1/24 \[Lambda] (6 \[Gamma]3 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] (-3 X[
           1] + \[Kappa] X[
           2]) - \[Gamma]3^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] (9 \[Lambda] \
- 8 X[4]) + 
      8 (-4 \[Gamma]1 + \[Kappa]) X[
        4] + \[Gamma]2^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] (9 \[Lambda] + 
         8 X[4]) - 
      2 \[Gamma]2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] (3 \[Kappa] X[1] - 
         9 X[2] - 8 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa] X[4])), -(1/
       24) \[Lambda] (\[Gamma]1 (9 \[Gamma]2^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \
\[Lambda] - 9 \[Gamma]3^2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) \[Lambda] + 
         6 \[Gamma]2 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) (\[Kappa] X[1] - 3 X[2]) - 
         6 \[Gamma]3 (-1 + \[Kappa]^2) (-3 X[1] + \[Kappa] X[2]) - 
         32 X[3]) + 
      2 (6 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa] (X[1] + \[Kappa] X[2]) + 
         4 \[Kappa] X[
           3] + \[Gamma]3^2 \[Lambda] (-15 \[Kappa] - 4 X[3] + 
            4 \[Kappa]^2 X[3]) + \[Gamma]2^2 \[Lambda] (15 \[Kappa] - 
            4 X[3] + 4 \[Kappa]^2 X[3]) + 
         2 \[Gamma]2 \[Kappa] (-3 \[Kappa] X[1] - 3 X[2] - 
            4 \[Gamma]3 \[Lambda] X[3] + 
            4 \[Gamma]3 \[Kappa]^2 \[Lambda] X[3])))};

GroebnerBasis[idealI, varsI, MonomialOrder -> Lexicographic] // 
  Factor // MatrixForm

(**********)


This is empty talk without your "exactly the same code" and the numbers of the versions.

The code is too large and complicated to include it here. I run exactly the same notebook. Mathematica versions are 12.1 and 13.3.

Maybe some function that GroebnerBasis is dependent on have change since old versions. Or maybe other functions there are in your notebook have changed that affect the later use of GroebnerBasis in your notebook.

There are no other functions in the notebook. Only GroebnerBasis[....]. I imagine that something has changed internally. I asked the question in case anyone had experienced something similar or if anyone has more information that I haven't found in the mathematica documentation.

@Ramon Try to find a minimal example that has different result on version 12.1 and 13.3 and then post it here.

Your code produces {(49 + 1000*X[3]^2)*X[4], 1 + 4*X[3]^2)*(49 + 1000*X[3]^2),   X[4]*(11200000*X[2]^4 -  720000*X[2]^2*X[3]*X[4] +     1183*X[4]^2), 2800000000*X[2]^4 + 11200000000*X[2]^4*X[3]^2 -    144720000*X[2]^2*X[3]*X[4] +  237783*X[4]^2, 420000*X[2]^3 +    1680000*X[2]^3*X[3]^2 + 6097*X[1]*X[4] - 44354*X[2]*X[3]*    X[4], (X[1] + 2*X[2]*X[3])* (49 + 1000*X[3]^2),   28140000*X[1]*X[2] - 143720000*X[2]^2*X[3] - 800000000*X[2]^2*X[3]^3 -    164619*X[4], 140*X[1]^2 + 140*X[2]^2 - 9*X[3]*X[4],   -5628*X[1] + 127744*X[2]*X[3] +556000*X[2]*X[3]^3 + 12663*\[Gamma]3*X[4], 

(3 + 8*\[Gamma]3*X[2])*(49 + 1000*X[3]^2),-80437*X[2] + 506520*\[Gamma]3*X[2]^2 -    57486*X[1]*X[3] - 1196500*X[2]* X[3]^2, 20636*\[Gamma]3*X[1] +    10573*X[3] - 67000*\[Gamma]3*X[2]*X[3] + 204700*X[3]^3, 139293*\[Gamma]2 -    6897086*\[Gamma]3*X[3] + 52260000*\[Gamma]3^2*    X[2]*X[3] - 104864000*\[Gamma]3*X[3]^3, 5477*\[Gamma]1 + 86000*X[3] -    804000*\[Gamma]3*X[2]*X[3] +1550000*X[3]^3, 21105*\[Lambda] -    30054880*X[2]^2*X[3] -121120000*X[2]^2*X[3]^3 - 37989*X[4], 5159*\[Kappa] +  430000*X[3] - 4020000*\[Gamma]3*X[2]*X[3] + 7750000*X[3]^3} in 14.0 on Windows 10.

Exactly as in v13.3. The problem is with previous versions (12 for example)

@Ramon Evaluate the following in both versions Sort[{\[Kappa], \[Lambda], \[Gamma]1, \[Gamma]2, \[Gamma]3, X[1],    X[2], X[3], X[4]}, LexicographicOrder]. If the outputs are different then there were made some changes in LexicographicOrder that affect GroebnerBasis.

@Ramon By the why it is written that LexicographicOrder was introduced in version 12.3 and you tried it on 12.1.

Thank you user64494 and azerbajdzan. I found that LexicographicOrder was introduced in 12.3, but indeed is also in the documentation for GroebnerBasis in 12.1. I have used the Sort function and I get different results in the two versions. So that's the problem. Thanks again.

Not sure about using Sort. LexicographicOrder is not a valid option for Sort function on 12.1. However, Lexicographic is valid for GroebnerBasis function (it is the default monomial order, as it is said in the documentation). So I still don't understand why GroebnerBasis[polys, vars] gives different results in the two versions. The history for this function indicates: Introduced in 1991 (2.0) | Updated in 1996 (3.0) ▪ 2007 (6.0). Maybe some related function has changed and it is influencing the way of calculating the Groebner basis. I can't think of any other possibility.

(1) It seems that one or two smallish heuristic changes that went into version 12.1 led to a substantial speed improvement for this example. (2) What Sort gives for the variable list is not relevant. GroebnerBasis by default will not sort the variables.

Daniel Lichtblau .- Thank you very much for your clarifications. Something like that is what I assumed.

In your different versions type
?GroebnerBasis
and click on Options.
